# React State variable is defined but its taking as undefined and receiving the error in the browser

Tags: reactjs, react-state

At the line **this.state inside constructor** , I am defining the value of **inStock : false** .In the **groupByCategory()** function i am having a **if( this.state.inStock )**. This results in undefined. But if I add a **'this.state?.inStock'** it works fine. Just trying to understand why this behaviour happens eventhough i initialized the state variable

```
const products = [
  { category: "Sporting Goods", price: "$49.99", stocked: true, name: "Football" },
  { category: "Sporting Goods", price: "$9.99", stocked: true, name: "Baseball" },
  { category: "Sporting Goods", price: "$29.99", stocked: false, name: "Basketball" },
  { category: "Electronics", price: "$99.99", stocked: true, name: "iPod Touch" },
  { category: "Electronics", price: "$399.99", stocked: false, name: "iPhone 5" },
  { category: "Electronics", price: "$199.99", stocked: true, name: "Nexus 7" }
];

type IProps = {

}

type IState = {
  query: string,
  inStock: boolean,
  group: {
    [name: string]: IProduct[]
  }
}
    class FilterableProductTable extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { query: '', inStock: false, group: this.groupByCategory(products) }
  }

  filterByName() {
    const filteredList = products.filter(each => {
      return each.name.startsWith(this.state.query)
    })
    this.groupByCategory(filteredList)
  }

  groupByCategory(list: IProduct[]) {
    let group = list.reduce((acc: any, next) => {
      const key = next.category
      if (!acc[key]) acc[key] = []
      if (this.state.inStock) { if (next.stocked) acc[key].push(next) }
      else acc[key].push(next)
      return acc
    }, {})
    this.setState({ group: group })
    return group
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I assume `this` is the `Array.reduce` context and not your class context. And as `state` does not exist in reduce context, you get the error. Optional chaining males this `undefined` instead of crashing, but your condition will always fail

Comment: No it's doesn't fail , it actually works as intended when I do the optional chaining. Now seeing the code I am realising this is because I am calling a function inside this.state inside constructor , and that functions use state.

Comment: Ok, wasn't sure that `reduce` has its own context, looks like it does not :)

Comment: this.state = {} assignment uses groupByCategory() for intializing the variable 'group' and then  the function groupByCategory() uses state variable to do some calculations. Thats why state is undefinded at that point of execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.state` has not been assigned to when `groupByCategory` is first called.

This is because you are calling `groupByCategory` *within* the initial value you're assigning to `this.state`

Before completing this line in the constructor:

```js
this.state = { query: '', inStock: false, group: this.groupByCategory(products) }
```

JS needs to figure out what will be in all of the object's properties *before* it completes the assignment.

So, first it attempts to resolve `group` by calling `groupByProperties` - at this point `this.state` *has not been assigned to*.

You can fix this by changing the constructor like so:

```js
constructor (props: IProps) {
  super(props)
  this.state = { query: '', inStock: false }
  this.state.group = this.groupByCategory(products)
}
```

This way, `this.state` and, more specifically, `this.state.inStock` have been assigned *before* you call `groupByCategory`.

Answer (score 0):

At the initialization of state variable `this.state = {query: '', inStock: false, group: this.groupByCategory(products)}`

groupByCategory() , this function actually uses state variable `inStock` as on of the calculation needs. So when initiazling the state, this.state is obviously undefined and thats why the error.